# How to check if a User Folder or any other Folder in DNN is empty?

Tags: dotnetnuke

​Hi,

Which code can I use to check if a User Folder or any other folder in DNN has no files? I have looked at: [Retrieve FileID from DotNetNuke using FileName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905268/retri)...​  but no luck.

Is this code correct to use to check if files exist? I don't want to specify a specific file name.

```
FolderManager.Instance.GetFiles();
```

What should come in the brackets for the code above? Can someone please provide an example?​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
FolderController controller = new FolderController();

Dictionary<string, FolderInfo> list = controller.GetFolders(PortalId);
foreach (var folder in list)
{
    List<IFileInfo> files = FolderManager.Instance.GetFiles(folder.Value).ToList();
    Label1.Text += folder.Key + ": " + files.Count();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Not that there are various overloads of `FolderManager.Instance.GetFiles`, many of them deprecated. But most of them still work.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing this as well using System.IO.Directory.

```
    var userfolderpath = FolderManager.Instance.GetUserFolder(UserInfo).FolderPath;
    var userfolderpath_ = @"\" + userfolderpath;
    var portalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Portals/" + this.PortalId);
    var physicalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(portalPath, userfolderpath);

            var list = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(physicalPath);
            if (list?.Length > 0)
            {
                //sumbit_files.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;");
                //message_container.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;");

                if (userfolderpath != null)
                {
                    dgrFileList.Columns[0].HeaderText = Localization.GetString("FileHeader", this.LocalResourceFile);
                    dgrFileList.Columns[1].HeaderText = Localization.GetString("FileWriteDate", this.LocalResourceFile);
                    dgrFileList.Columns[2].HeaderText = Localization.GetString("FileDownloadHeader", this.LocalResourceFile);
                    dgrFileList.DataSource = FileUtility.GetSafeFileList(string.Concat(portalPath, userfolderpath_), GetExcludedFiles(), GetSortOrder());
                    dgrFileList.DataBind();
                }
            }
```